a number of people who

"If you put a large red door on a roundabout, there are a large number of people who are so wrapped up in their world that they simply don't see it.

Source: https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-27884890

Grammatically, does "who" refer to "a number of people" or does it refer to just "people"?
Is the object of "of" "people who are so wrapped up in their world that they simply don't see it"?


The artist's name is IMPRO , what does propl refer to? Is it a typo for people?

A large number of is just another way of saying many.

Consider the noun "people" being modified by the phrase beginning "who are so wrapped...". Logically, one cannot refer to a number with the pronoun who.
